# Can native attributes be used as bind target in parameters?

Tags: syntax, raku

According to the [6.d (current version) check list](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/2632), they can.

However,

```
class Foo { 
    has num $.numillo;
    submethod BUILD( :$numillo = 3.5 ) {}
};
my $foo = Foo.new;
say $foo.raku; # OUTPUT:  «Foo.new(numillo => 0e0)␤»
```

The atttribute does not seem to be bindable, or at least does not get a value assigned. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are just assigning a value to a named parameter in `BUILD`, **not** to the attribute!

```
submethod BUILD( :$!numillo = 3.5e0 ) {}
```

should fix that (note the **!** in the signature).  Please also note that `3.5` is **not** a `num`, you would have to make it one by adding `e0`.